# Memory-less property of Exponential distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-function

X follows exponential distribution, when $p.d.f.$ of random variable $X$ is $$f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x},\ x \ge 0$$

, where $E(X)=\displaystyle\frac1\lambda$.

---

### Problem

A cellphone, which can be used 50 hours on average after charged, follows exponential distribution.

$$
\mbox{X: the time that the cellphone can be used after charged.}\\
X \sim Exp(0.02) \left(\because E(X)=\frac 1 \lambda = 50,\ \therefore\lambda = 0.02\right)
$$

Q$_1$) Find the probability that the cellphone will be used more than 48 hours after charging.

A$_1$) $P(X\gt48)=1-F(48)=e^{\lambda x}\big|_{\lambda=0.02,~x=48}=e^{-0.96}=0.3829$

---

I don't understand why the answer is 0.3829.

Because average is $50$, $P(X>48)$, and $50$ is larger than $48$, I naively thought the answer is larger than $0.5$.

Why the answer is elicited as 0.3829?

Comment: Essentially because the exponential distribution is right-skewed, and the median (i.e. the half-life of the battery) is smaller than the mean (the mode is *much* smaller)

Comment: If so, is it right to apply exponential distribution into this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not compare it with the mean,
you should compare 48 with the median which is $\frac{ln(2)}{0.02}\approxeq 35$ .
As $48>35$ the probability is less tha 0.5.

Comment: Ah, now I slightly understand. $\frac{\ln(2)}{0.02}$ is from $\int_0^t{0.02e^{-0.02x}}dx=0.5$, isn't it?

Comment: yes. it is called the median of the distribution.

Comment: I have to pore on this answer with more time. Thank you for giving me a good clue.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I am wondering if I can regard Exponential-distribution as continuous-Poisson-distribution. As far as I am concerned, it seems to similar distribution just discrete version and continuous version.

Comment: @Danny No, you can't. Exponential is a continuous version of a geometric though.

Comment: Ah!!, Thank you. So interesting probability and so difficult :)